# references are ovelapping in bibliography fancy header

Tags: bibliographies, header-footer

The first two references in each column of the bibliography are coming in way of the heading which is the blue region. I want to start the references below the blue region. I want them to be shifted vertically downwards by an inch. The rest of my chapters in my thesis has the same heading style but no problem there. I am using a .bib file for bibliography. i am attaching a picture. I am using the command for bibliography as

```
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\begin{tiny}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\twocolumn
\bibliography{citations}
\onecolumn
\end{tiny}
```

What to do?

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you refering to being a problem here? I see no overlap in that image

Comment: A tiny bibliography?  Who can read that?

Comment: the fancy background of the heading of the bibliography consists of the blue coloured area. The first two references in each column of the bibliography is getting in way of this heading backgraound. I want to start the references on the page where the blue box ends.  Or in other words I want the references to have a downward vertical shift by one inch.